# iPhone SMS: Same Contact, Different Phone Numbers

Tags: iphone, sms

Is there any way to differentiate between a contact with different phone numbers in Messages?

Answer (score 4):

Select the contact in the Messages app, then scroll to top and tap `Contact Info`.

The number to which this thread is sent to is highlighted.

But there is no way to know that from the "homepage", at least without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 1):

First, open the Messages app.
Next, click the new message button in the top right of the screen.
Begin typing the name of the contact you want to text and you will see a list of their different phone numbers.  Select the one you want to message.

You won't be able to differentiate the numbers based on the name of the contact, but you will get a different chat thread for each phone number.